# Is there a reward for 100 jumps in the Jump-Rope Challenge?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In New Donk City, there is a group of people playing with a jump rope. Mario can join in to try and earn a high score.

After winning a moon for achieving 30 jumps, a nearby man said "*I wonder if anyone has ever done 100 jumps..."*. I'm not sure if this was simply encouraging me to get a high score, or if this was a specific goal I should aim for.

**Is there a reward for getting 100 jumps in the Jump-Rope challenge?**

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It took a few attempts, but you can earn two power moons by playing the Jump-Rope challenge.

- 30 jumps: (***#29: Jump-Rope Hero***)
- 100 jumps: (***#30: Jump-Rope Genius***)

[Any score above 100 jumps](https://twitter.com/artsyomni/status/924328894223720449) is just for bragging rights on the online leaderboard.